# Have you passed him the books yet (that) he had asked?

Tags: relative-clauses

If I ask "Have you passed him the books he had asked?", I don't need "that" after "the books". But does this rule work if I add "yet" after "the books":

> Have you passed him **the books yet** he had asked?
>
> Have you passed him **the books yet that** he had asked?

Is there a need to use "that" in this case?

Comment: A native speaker would say "the books he asked _for_". We don't want to separate _books_ from the phrase identifying them, so _yet_ has to go at the end. "Have you passed him the books he asked for yet?"

Comment: Or: ".....passed him the books that he requested."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative pronoun "that" is optional. Inserting the adverb "yet" doesn't change that.

However, there are some other issues:

1. Even if you omit "that", it is understood:

> Have you passed him the books yet [[that]] he had asked?

The relative pronoun "that" refers to "the books" and functions as the direct object of "asked". However, it makes no sense for a person to ask books. Either of these would be better:

> Have you passed him the books yet [[that]] he had asked for?
> Have you passed him the books yet [[that]] he had requested? (as RS suggested in a comment)

2. Some people suggested the past tense ("asked") instead of the past perfect ("had asked"). The past perfect is fine, making clear that the "asking" occurred before the "passing".
3. Some people suggested moving "yet" to the end of the sentence. However, it is possible that someone might then think that it modified "had asked".* Furthermore, while long elements are often postponed, there is often less need to postpone shorter ones. I therefore like "yet" where it is.

*A reader should realize that "yet" does not modify "had asked" in this sentence. However, there might be some brief confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed him the books yet he had asked?----
Have you passed him the books he had asked FOR, yet? Yet is put at the end of a sentence. "YOU" did not ask the books but asked FOR the books. THAT is often unnecessary.